# Cannot use "ge" as attribute for custom object on Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm building a component that has a list of a custom object. When user does something specific on this component, some background work is done so that each item on this list can receive some attributes of country codes, like `us` for USA and `ge` for Germany.

I tried to save a component with the following markup, and got an error instead:

> [ERROR]: expecting an identifier, found 'ge' at column 6 of expression: item.ge != undefined: Source

My code is as follows:

```
...
<li>
  <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
    <span class="slds-m-right--small">
      <div>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!item.ge != undefined}">
          {!item.ge}
          <aura:set attribute="else">
            0
          </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
      </div>
    </span>
    <img src="{!$Resource.famfamfamflagpack + '/png/de.png'}"></img>
  </button>
</li>
...
```

And there are more elements on this HTML List, that have the same markup, but with different country codes, and I can only save when `ge` isn't on the list.

Is this a bug? For now I guess my best workaround is to use `de` instead, which is fine by me. But it's really weird not to be able to save the component because of an attribute.

Comment: can you share the beginning of the markup - to see how item is defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. I'll ask around. For reference, ge is a synonym for ">=" (greater-or-equal-to), as noted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm), which is probably why it isn't compiling correctly.

Comment: Confirming: this error happens when trying to save the component with the values specified on that table.